# How can I understand differences between React.Component and Higher-Order Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have used to this code style before.

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>This is my app</>
    );
  }
}
```

But now, I see all things are Higher-Order Components.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <>This is my app</>
  );
}
```

I haven't understood about them. Sometimes, I read an example written in the class style and can't convert ideas into the Higher-Order Components. Please explain to me or give me some related keywords, posts or other types of document?

Thank you!

Comment: That is not a Higher-Order Component but a functional component.

Comment: The second example is just a simple functional component, not a higher order component.

Comment: That's just class vs. function components, see https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out my problem.

- Firstly, they are differences between Class and Function Component, not Higher-Order Component.
- Secondly, to convert Class component to Function component, I have to understand how to add state and lifecycle methods to both of them.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
https://itnext.io/add-state-and-lifecycle-methods-to-function-components-with-react-hooks-8e2bdc44d43d

Thanks for giving some useful comments!

Question is closed.